# date returned as datetime in eloquent / laravel

Tags: php, laravel

what I want:

when I return my model as json of a *date* column I get `2010-10-10 00:00:00`
this is wrong, as the date is stores as `2010-10-10` not with time.

a bit confusing

the [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) of the laravel docs are actually 'datetime' mutators. `created_at` etc are datetimes. Not dates. So seems like poor selection of the name 'dates'. That should be 'dateTimesAndDates'. Now I don't want to change the dateTime format for all fields, just for all dates to return only the date, what is my best option? use a mutator for each date column?

my model:

```
class MyUser extends Eloquent
{
  protected $guarded = [
      'id', 'user_id'
  ];

    protected $dates = [
        'birthdate'
    ];
```

treat birthdate not as date but string instead?

Comment: `protected $dates = [stuff]` will convert stuff to an instance of `Carbon` and set the time to `00:00:00`.  Carbon's `__toString()` implementation outputs this format. If you don't need to perform actions on the attribute very often and already have it saved in a format that you need it in, might as well treat it as a string. Or you could make an accessor.

Comment: Actually it won't even set to `00:00:00`, `protected $casts = ['something' => 'date']` will do that.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your column type in database is DateTime not Date.

You can fix this problem.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function getBirthdateAttribute($value){
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

OR

In your migration file make the column as date

```
$table->date('birthdate');
```

Comment: Then use the accessor. and create a format what ever you want. As shown above.